# ASP.Net Core 2.0 and logging

Tags: logging, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.0

I generated a new project for ASP.Net Core 2.0. Added this code in `Program.cs`:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
{
    loggerFactory.AddConsole();
    ...
```

Then I go to the folder containing the project and run `dotnet run`:

```
Hosting environment: Development
Content root path: C:\Users\arthur\Source\Repos\WebApplication5\WebApplication5
Now listening on: http://localhost:3000
Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down
```

While navigating the site I want to see the logs generated by framework but I see nothing. Though if I generate ASP.Net Core 1.1 web project the lines with logging are already in `Program.cs` and I see the logs:

```
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost[1]
      Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://localhost:53680/
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker[1]
      Executing action method WebApplication3.Controllers.HomeController.Index (WebApplication3) with arguments ((null)) - ModelState is Valid
```

What am I missing?

Comment: as per MSDN you need to add `.AddDebug();` to program.cs if you want core to log the changes, but you need to use log `LogWarning``LogInformation` to log things you want.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/logging

Comment: `AddDebug()` just adds logging to debug console of visual studio, with `Log[Level]` you just log what *you* want to log and I am interested in logs produced by ASP.Net itself, like ` Executing action method WebApplication3.Controllers.HomeController.Index (WebApplication3) with arguments ((null)) - ModelState is Valid`

Comment: Did you check https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/logging#log-filtering

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ok, I feel a bit stupid now, but to achieve what I wanted I had to change `LogLevel` of `Debug` and `Console` in appsettings.json to something lower that `Warning`

Comment: You could also add a file `appsettings.Development.json` to overwrite the LogLevel only for the Development environment. The method CreateDefaultBuilder in Program.cs automatically adds the configurations for the current environment.